# retrieve data into a JTable that tally with the date input by the user from a JDateChooser

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception, data-retrieval

I am using `Netbeans` 8.0.2 for GUI creation and `MYSQL` `Query Browser` for the database.There is a `JInternalFrame` form called `LCI` in my Java project and in that Interface I have a JDateChooser called `DATE` and a `JButton` called  `Load_To_Table`.I need to retrieve data from the DB table called `LCI` which I have created already and connected with the project.

At first user has to choose a date from `DATE` and then click `Load_To_Table`. Then the application should check whether there is a record available that tally with the `DATE` input.If so, it should retrieve that record into a `JTable` called `tb1`.

Below is my code.

```
private void Load_To_TableActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        try{

            Statement s = DB.getConnection().createStatement();
            DefaultTableModel dtm=(DefaultTableModel)tb1.getModel();
            Vector v=new Vector();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            ResultSet rs,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rs5;

            rs1=j.getData("select E_ID from User where E_ID='"+user+"'");

           if(rs1.next()==true) 
           {

               rs=j.getData("select * from LCI where L_DATE= '"+dateFormat.format(DATE.getDate())+"'");

               if(rs.next()== true)
               {
                   v.add(rs.getString("L_ID"));
                   v.add(rs.getString("HEADING"));
                   v.add(rs.getString("INSTITUTE"));
                   v.add(rs.getString("L_DATE"));
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Successful");
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println(rs.getString("L_DATE"));
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "There is no data related to the date you entered.Please try another date.");
               }

           }
           else{
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Failed to connect with DB. Please try again");
           }
        }
        catch(Exception  ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

But it gives an error saying that it is an illegal operation or an empty `result set`.

Below is the stack trace.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:855)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5773)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5693)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5733)
    at Viewer.LCI.Load_To_TableActionPerformed(LCI.java:668)
    at Viewer.LCI.access$800(LCI.java:25)
    at Viewer.LCI$9.actionPerformed(LCI.java:342)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 minutes 7 seconds)
```

Can anyone please tell me how should I amend the code to get done what I have described in second paragraph of this description (to retrieve data that tally with the date input by the user).Thanks in advance.

Comment: With out the `getData` method it's going to be hard to provide an accurate answer. However, I would recommend that you start by having a look at [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of using string concatenation to form your queries

Comment: I would suggest that you start by printing out the two SQL queries to the command line, or get them from your debugger.  Then execute them against MySQL manually and look at the data that comes back.  Is it what you expect?

Comment: Since you might produce an `SQLException` with code invoked from the command line, that is how this should be debugged at the moment. It really does not have anything to do with Swing (yet). Break the problem down into smaller parts and get each working separately.

Comment: Thank you very much @MadProgrammer
 I'd look into that and try  :)  .

Comment: Thank you very much @Riaan 
I think I didn't get properly what you have said. Extremely sorry about that.I am new to advanced programming. 
What I need to do is to insert a date using JDateChooser and check whether that date is already exist in the LCI table. If exist, I need to retrieve those existing records (rows of data) into the JTable. I don't use a command line. All I use is Netbeans and Query browser.

Comment: @Andrew :) I am not using command line. I used ctrl + F5 to debug the project so far. First I need to correct the date comparison part I guess. Is it?

Comment: *"I am not using command line."* Well, maybe you can use the IDE, but my point is, leave the GUI out of it, and don't add the tags to the question here. Get the DB access sorted out first!